# PHP Fatal error: Smarty error: syntax error: unidentified token '='

Tags: smarty

Could someone point me in the right direction.

```
{if $current_url == '/movies' || $current_url == '/tv-shows' || $current_url == '/movie/$mov.title|replace:' ':'-''}
```

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong to get this error because i'm new to coding.

PHP Fatal error: Smarty error: syntax error: unidentified token '='

Comment: removed PHP tag because PHP users who don't understand smarty are going to be pretty confused by this question.

Comment: The ending seems to be confused for me. What is that replace there? and what are the last apostrophe encapsulated string?

Comment: Well what i'm trying to do is the current url looks like this `/movie/the-host` so i'm trying to use the movie title as the end of the url that looks like this `the host` and i'm to replace spaces with `-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using quotes wrong. This is not valid, because you're embedding single quotes inside single quotes:

```
$current_url == '/movie/$mov.title|replace:' ':'-''
```

Instead, you should use this:

```
$current_url == '/movie/'|cat:$mov.title|replace:' ':'-'
```

Or the somewhat shorter version with backticks:

```
$current_url == "/movie/`$move.title`":$mov.title|replace:' ':'-'
```